# Kotlin: How can inflate Room data into a RecyclerView using Fragments?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-room

I trying use Room to inflate the Database in an RecyclerView, but all this using Fragments. I have the screen where the user enters the data and the screen where the RecyclerView is inflated,  but I don't know how to make the Room data inflate in the RecyclerView and I still can't understand the viewModel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

For Getting data from Room [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data) might get helpful
and for view modal [this](https://proandroiddev.com/flexible-recyclerview-adapter-with-mvvm-and-data-binding-74f75caef66a) helped me.

after getting data from Room you can simply notify the adapter.

example :

```
    var myList = ArrayList<YourModel>()
    roomDataList.forEach { item ->
//You can parse or convert your data according to your use
    myList.add(item)
    }
    adapter.updateList(myList)
```